# Server CPU at 100 Percent and not responding using PUMA and Nginx

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails

My Server CPU is at 100 percent and not responding using PUMA and Nginx after one or two days. I use 4 workers.
Up to now I had a look at the problem with strace, which leads to the following Output

`futex(0x20f0f64, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0x20f0f60, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1}) = 1
futex(0x20f0f30, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0x20f0f98, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0x20f0f9c, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2376235, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)`

A look at the FD showed that the Resource her is "puma.sock"
Does anyone has an idea how to get closer to the problem?

Comment: What is your hardware configuration?

Comment: Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):   32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                12
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-11
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    6
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 45
Stepping:              7
CPU MHz:               1200.000
BogoMIPS:              6400.26
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              12288K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-11